# how to pass array of int to a function that accept array of float

Tags: c

I want pass an array of int to an array that have array of float parameter
this is what I tried, it do compile but it give rubbish results !

```
function_1(float arr*, int len)
{
  ....
  ....
}

main()
{
     int samp[5] = {-1, 3, 5, 10, 20};
     function_1((float *)samp, 5); //not correct !
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. -- You cannot do this. Why do you need it? Please [edit] your question and explain why you have the `int` array in the first place.

Comment: You will need to pass a `float[]` which means you'll have to cast each and every `int` member of the array into a `float`. Remember, while ints and floats are **usually** both 4-bytes long, floats follow the IEEE754 while ints don't. Thats partially why you're getting rubbish results.

Comment: The parameter list of the function is the contract you must stick to when using that function. Passing anything else is cheating and wont result in any good.

Comment: @thebusybee its simple, I want to learn C and I want to know what is possible and what is not possible and I couldn't find a direct answer from searching so I asked help.

Comment: @Shark is there a way to cast each int to float inside the function before elaborating the data ?

Comment: @skydriver it might be easiest to make a new `float[] castIntsToFloats(int[] ints)` method, which you'll call before passing it to `function_1`. Something along the lines of `function_1(castIntsToFloats(samp), 5)`

Comment: @Shark I thought about this solution but I don't won't to iterate 2 times to this. And since C don't accept function overloading I think I will create a similar function that accept int. Anyway thanks for help.

Comment: Casting is almost never the correct solution in beginner-level programs. Most of the time it just tells the compiler "shut up, I don't know what I'm doing!" :)

Comment: @skydriver Unrelted to your problem, but since you're learning: If you're doing ordinary floating-point work, you should get in the habit of using type `double`, not `float`.  Unless you have special requirements, using `float` won't buy you much of anything, and it will often cost you a lot in terms of precision and roundoff error.

Comment: @SteveSummit I use float for space saving and because there is no precision requirements but thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. No computer have the same internal and bitwise representation of `float` and `int`. Not to mention that `sizeof(float)` doesn't have to be equal to `sizeof(int)`.

The only solution is to create a new array, and convert each and every element from `int` to `float`, and then pass the proper array of `float`.

Comment: This. exactly what i said :D

Comment: so even if sizeof(float) equal to sizeof(int), there is no way to cast the array inside the function after receiving it ?

Comment: @skydriver The binary format of `float` is different from `int`.

Comment: @skydriver C is a relatively low-level language.  There are some little things it will do for you automatically, but creating an entirely new array of `float`, and converting N integers from your `samp` array to populate is, is not the sort of thing that C is ever, ever going to do behind your back.  The syntax `(float *)samp` does not actually attempt to do anything to the array `samp`.  All it does is make a slight alteration to the pointer (the single pointer) which is being passed to `function_1`.

Comment: @SteveSummit yes now I understand that (float *) is doing nothing

Comment: @skydriver Well, no, the `(float *)` cast does do one thing: it silences the message the compiler otherwise would have given you, warning you that `function_1` wasn't going to be able to operate on `samp`, and was going to give you rubbish results!